# Sublime Key Binding "TAB" to exit parenthesis, quotes etc, EXCEPT when it is the first character on the line

Tags: configuration, sublimetext3, config, sublimetext, key-bindings

I'm trying to get "TAB" to exit parenthesis, quotes, etc. but only when it is NOT the only character on the line. If | represents the cursor:

Exit here:

```
function(e|) {}
```

But not here:

```
function() {
  return;
|}
```

To do so I'm trying to set the context to check for that condition without any success. Here is what I have so far:

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "move", "args": {"by": "characters", "forward": true}, "context":
[
    { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_contains", "operand": "^[)'}\"\\]]", "match_all": true },
    { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "not_regex_match", "operand": "\\n", "match_all":true },
    { "key": "auto_complete_visible", "operator": "equal", "operand": false }
]
}
```

The second line of the context is what I can't get right. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Best,

Michael

Comment: Just change `\\n` to `^` or `^\\s*`.

Comment: Indeed, using ```^\\s*``` works perfectly. Thanks! (If you post an answer I can accept it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to match until the line start you should use `^`. The regex match is only per line, hence you can use `^` for the begin and `$` for the end of the line.
Change it to `^\\s*` if you also want to disable it for lines with indent, e.g. to press the tab multiple times to indent the bracket.